# Find the projection of the line $x+y+z-3=0=2x+3y+4z-6$ on the plane $z=0$

Tags: geometry, vectors, 3d

> Find the projection of the line $x+y+z-3=0=2x+3y+4z-6$ on the plane $z=0$

The equation represents the line of intersection of two planes. Using augmented matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
2 & 3 & 4 & 6
\end{bmatrix}$$

$R_2\rightarrow R_2-2R_1$
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & 2 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$y+2z=0$$
$$x+y+z=3$$
Equation of line is
$$\frac{x-0}{1}=\frac{y-0}{-2}=\frac{z-0}{1}$$

Angle made by line and normal is $$\cos(90-\theta)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}$$
where $\theta$ is the angle made by line and plane.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note:

I get 
$$
y + 2z = 0 \Rightarrow z = - y/2 \\
3 + z = (x + y + z) + z = x + y + 2z = x
$$
So 
$$
\frac{x - 3}{1} = \frac{y-0}{-2} = \frac{z - 0}{1}
$$
or
$$
(x, y, z) = (3,0,0) + t (1, -2, 1)
$$
Hint: The projection onto $z=0$ should affect what coordinate?

Spoiler:

> The $z$-coordinate is forced to $0$. So we have $(x,y,z) = (3,0,0) + t (1,-2,0)$. We have $y = - 2 t$ and $x - 3 = t$ so $y = -2(x-3) = -2x + 6$ is the equation of the projected line within the $x$-$y$-plane.

Comment: so i made a calculation mistake?

Comment: I believe you did.

Answer (score 2):

A line passes through two points.

You can get the first point intersecting your line with the plane $z=0$. $p=(3,0,0)$.

Simply project another random point of your line, say $(0,6,-3)$, in the plane $z=0$, you get $q=(0,6,0)$.

The line you are looking for is thus $z=0$, $y=-2x+6$.